# Submitting a form within a jquery UI dialog on iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, forms, dialog, submit

I have a jquery UI Dialog with a form in it, which i want to submit after hitting the OK-Button.

```
    function JQDialogOKCancel(title, text, width) {
    $( '#JQDialog' ).html(text);
    $( '#JQDialog' ).dialog({ 
        title: title,
        width: width,
        height: 'auto',
        buttons: {
            OK: function() {
                $( 'form' ).submit(),
                $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
            },
            Abbrechen: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I think you all know what comes now. $( 'form').submit() is not working on iPads. Is there a simple way to get that fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just to let an answer here to help people with the same problem...

I didn't manage to find a solution so I created a dialog without buttons and put "OK" and "Cancel" into the form itself. (which is in the variable "text")

To avoid a page refresh after hitting "Cancel" I used an onClick on the Cancel-button and then do something like this:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```